# Combine site content with external site rss

Tags: php, mysql, rss

I'm currently running a classified ads site and planning to display my own content combined with and external site rss.
So here is what i got right now after the db query for the jobs ads,

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){


    echo '<div class="media margin-none">
           <a class="pull-left bg-inverse innerAll text-center" href="#"><img src="'.$foto.'"    share_alt="" width="100" height="100"></a>
            <div class="media-body innerAll">
             <h4 class="media-heading innerT">
              <a href="' . $row['title'] .'-da' . $row['id_ad'] . '" class="text-inverse">'. $remuneracion .' &nbsp; ' . substr(ucfirst(strtolower($row['title'])), 0, 53) . '</a> <small class="pull-right label label-default"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-calendar-o"></i> ' . $row['date_created'] . '</small></h4>                                           
            <p>' . substr(ucfirst(strtolower($row['description'])), 0, 80) . ' ...</p>';

    echo '</div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-separator-h"></div>';
}   

echo pagination($statement,$per_page,$page, $url_filtros, $filtros);
?>
```

it is the while loop that i use to display ads from my database, what could be the best way to display (in this same loop?) other site's rss feed?

Thanks

Comment: it depends on what to really need to do, just get the feed first outside the loop gather those data, then when you fetch the db values, just add the fetch rss inside. DO NOT fetch the external content inside the loop

Comment: Have you got an example of the rss from the other site and your DB results?